# Codeigniter mysql query using UNION to select values equal to today's date first

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to modify the following query from a model on Codeigniter:

```
public $table                 = 'fi_client_notes';
public $primary_key           = 'fi_client_notes.client_note_id';

public function default_select()
{
    $this->db->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fi_client_notes.*, fi_clients.client_name", FALSE);

    if ($this->session->userdata('user_id') <> 1)
    {
        $this->db->where('fi_clients.user_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    }
}

public function default_order_by()
{
        $this->db->order_by('fi_client_notes.client_note_date DESC');
}

public function default_join()
{
    $this->db->join('fi_clients', 'fi_clients.client_id = fi_client_notes.client_id');
}
```

My goal is to select first only the rows where the value "fi_client_notes.client_note_end" is equal to today's date, then show all the rest of the rows arranged in descending order based on the value "fi_client_notes.client_note_date".

This is the query I'm trying:

```
(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS fi_clients.client_name, fi_client_notes.* FROM (`fi_client_notes`) JOIN `fi_clients` ON `fi_clients`.`client_id` = `fi_client_notes`.`client_id` WHERE `fi_client_notes`.`client_note_end` = CURDATE())
UNION
(SELECT fi_clients.client_name, fi_client_notes.* FROM (`fi_client_notes`) JOIN `fi_clients` ON `fi_clients`.`client_id` = `fi_client_notes`.`client_id`
ORDER BY `fi_client_notes`.`client_note_date` DESC LIMIT 15)
```

But I don't know how to use it on Codeigniter, since CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord doesn't support UNION

Answer (score 1):

in this case you can get result without union, just add `n.client_note_end <> CURDATE()` as top level for order by clause

```
SELECT c.client_name, n.* 
     FROM `fi_client_notes` as n 
       JOIN
          `fi_clients` as c
         ON c.`client_id` = n.`client_id`
     ORDER BY (n.`client_note_end` <> CURDATE()),
              `n.`client_note_date` DESC LIMIT 15
```

Comment: That works perfectly, although I don't understand the meaning of `ORDER BY (n.client_note_end <> CURDATE()),
              n.client_note_date DESC LIMIT 15`. What does <> mean in this case?

Comment: really it sorted by `0 . n.client_note_date` and `1 . n.client_note_date` because mysql casts boolean false and true to 0 and 1

Comment: <> means `not equal` so with today date it returns false

Comment: @DavidM have you understood?

Comment: Not really, I just could verify it works exactly as expected. What happens if it returns true?

Comment: mysql cast it to 1 and all this records will be placed after that for which 0 (false) returned, because we sort the first key ascending. And then keys are sorted  descending in each group